# Is my shop currently open? using Carbon

Tags: php, schedule, php-carbon

I'm trying the following:

I have two models: Pub and Schedule, that stores different schedules of a given pub. For this reason the relation between this two models is 1 pub->N schedules:

### Pub:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function pubSchedules()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class);
}
```

### Schedule:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function pub()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Pub::class);
}
```

The table "schedules" has the following fields:

id|pub_id|week_day|opening_time|closing_time

For example, for pub wit id =303, we have the following schedule

id| pub_id|week_day|opening_time|closing_time
'9',  '303', '5',    '00:00:00', '02:30:00'
'10', '303', '5',    '10:30:00', '13:30:00'
'11', '303', '5',    '20:00:00', '23:59:00'

I'm trying to do a function to know if a given pub is currently open or not, but as I don't know very much about Carbon I'm having some problems to figure out.

I'd like to know how can I compare the current time with the different opening and closing times of a given pub during the day, and know if current time is inside or not an interval of time the pub is open.

I tried this (I want function return a message "open/closed"):

(rough version)

```
public function isPubCurrentlyOpen(Pub $pub)
{
    $dayOfWeek = Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek;

    $schedules = Schedule::where([
        ['pub_id', $pub->id ],
        ['week_day', $dayOfWeek],
    ])->get();

    foreach($schedules as $schedule)
    {
        if(var_dump($dayOfWeek->between($schedule->opening_time, $schedule->closing_time))){
            return "Open";
        }

    }
}
```

Please, could you help me?
Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you comparing day of week with opening hours? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: WOW!! sorry, inside foreach it would be Carbon::now(). Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
$isOpen = 
    // check if day of week matches
    Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek === $schedule->week_day &&
    // check if current time is greater than or equal than today's opening time
    Carbon::now()->gte(Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->opening_time)) &&
    // check if current time is less than or equal than today's closing time
    Carbon::now()->lte(Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->closing_time));
```

**UPDATE:** as suggested by Thomas below, you can simplify the code by using the **between** method:

```
$isOpen = 
    Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek === $schedule->week_day &&
    Carbon::now()->between(
      Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->opening_time),
      Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->closing_time)
    );
```

Comment: carbon has a `between` function

Comment: thanks a lot!!, I did this, but it must return "Pub Closed", do you know why it doesnt work?  foreach ($schedules as $schedule){
            $isOpen =
                Carbon::now()->between(
                    Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->opening_time),
                    Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->closing_time)
                );

            if($isOpen === true){
                return "Pub Opened";
            }else{
                return "Pub Closed";
            }

        }

Comment: but your answer is good point to start improving, thanks a lot brother!!

Comment: You prob need to check all the schedules first and only if none of them isOpen, return isClosed

Answer (score 0):

### Solution (thanks to jedrzej.kurylo and Thomas Moors):

```
public function isPubCurrentlyOpen(Pub $pub)
{
    $dayOfWeek = Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek;

    $schedules = Schedule::where([
        ['pub_id', $pub->id ],
        ['week_day', $dayOfWeek],
    ])->get();

    foreach ($schedules as $schedule){
        $isOpen[] =
            Carbon::now()->between(
                Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->opening_time),
                Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString($schedule->closing_time)
            );
    }

    if(in_array(true, $isOpen)){
        return "Pub Opened";
    }

    return "Pub Closed";
}
```